# How to extend a generic class with added constraints in java?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I want to extend my BinaryTree class so that only Integer parameters are accepted and I can reuse the code.

```
public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<T>>  
{/*code omitted for convenience*/}  
public class BinaryTreeInt<T extends Integer> extends BinaryTree<T>  
{/*code omitted for convenience*/}
```

I get following error on compilation-

```
BinaryTreeInt.java:1: type parameter T is not within its bound
public class BinaryTreeInt<T extends Integer> extends BinaryTree<T>
                                                                 ^
1 error
```

Can someone guide how to write code for such inheritance?

Comment: Why is the second class generic at all?

Comment: are you sure of <T extends Integer> ? Integer is a final class so extends it has no sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer is final so what you have is

```
public class BinaryTreeInt extends BinaryTree<Integer>
```

However the type implies its is `int` rather than `Integer`

Comment: True, but, why does the code in the question gets that compilation error?

Comment: I think it's because T is not able to extend the Integer and hence not implementing Comparable.

Comment: @user877856: No; that's not why.  It's because `T` isn't constrained to extend `Comparable<T>`.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from the following potential class:

```
class FunnyNumber extends Integer { }
```

This class does not extend `Comparable<T>`, so it can't be used as the base `T`.
In other words, `extends Comparable<Integer>` is not the same as `extends Comparable<T>`.

Your second class should not be generic at all.
You should only use generics if you want to *vary* the type parameter.
Here, you want a single fixed type, so you should make a normal non-generic class that extends `BinaryTree<Integer>`.  (or just use `BinaryTree<Integer>` directly and don't make a separate class at all)

Comment: I must be missins something obvious, but I don't get what you say. The code you posted doesn't make sense, it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Pablo: Ignoring the fact that `Integer` is sealed, this class is an example of a derived `T` doesn't satisfy the base constraint.

Comment: OK, I think you meant to write FunnyNumber extends Integer. Now I understand, Comparable<Integer> a; Comparable<FunnyNumber> b; a = b; would not compile.